# Add file as parameter

Tags: teamcity

I want to attach a file as `env` parameter. But in settings there is only `text` type of parameter. I couldn't just copy-past from file and add it as plain text. Because the file has a binary type(could be open with `pickle` etc). Is it some other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Add a parameter containing path to this file instead.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for passing a file as a parameter would be to :

- copy the file to all the build agents that can run the build (at location `%FileAsParamLocation%`)
- pass its location as a build parameter : `%FileAsParamLocation%`

If you have only one build agent, or if all your build agents run on the same machine, then you only need to copy the file once. Else you should copy the parameter-file to every agent, at the same `%FileAsParamLocation%`.